# Joomla obtain SEF Frontend URL from a model in backend

Tags: php, joomla

I am making a custom component in Joomla which needs to send a mail to user. I use the model to send the mail from the backend admin section. The model uses this code :

```
$btn_link = JURI::root().substr(JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_mymailer&view=messages&email={$myMsg->email}&tid={$myMsg->ticket_id}");
```

Then I use the above link as an anchor on a button on email body and send through JMAIL. However the link that arrives is a non-sef one (as SEF is not applicable on backend). This is the link I get :

```
http://testsite.com/index.php?option=com_mymailer&view=messages&email=mytestmail@gmail.com&tid=27
```

Whereas the result I want is (a menu is present named as mails):

```
http://testsite.com/mails/messages/index.php?email=mytestmail@gmail.com&tid=27
```

Do any body have an idea how to get SEF frontend URLs from the backend code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component)

Comment: Ofcourse I have seen that page, but that page doesnt have any solution for my problem or anywhere close.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's quite outdated but it's the first (relevant) result on Google.
So you need the site (frontend) router and an ItemID. That's all. J!2.5

```
//get the frontend Application to create the full object chain
$siteApp = JApplication::getInstance('site');

//now you can use the router for the frontend
$siteRouter = $siteApp->getRouter();

//get the itemid as you wish
//you can use frontend menu object
$siteMenu = $siteApp->getMenu();

//you need a correct itemid in $yourUri to route correctly
/* there's a little glitch, maybe with JURI::root so it still uses 
the admin subdir anyways, but simply remove it. 
maybe better to check if it's at the beginning of the string 
but now it's your business */

$sefURI = str_replace('/administrator',NULL,$siteRouter->build($yourUri));
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want requires two major things.  The first is to have the link endpoint be to a front end MVC path where the model class extends the custom messages model in the back end.

Which brings us to point 2.  You can either create a menutype which is not displayed on the website via the mod_menus module, and add a menu link to the front end view with the alias holding what you would like the alias to be.  This provides Joomla a reference point.  That's the quick and dirty method.  The "proper" method would be to write a router.php script and place in your components root site folder.

If you write the router.php script, this will enable the automated formatting of URLs to SEF format when using JRoute::_() with one caveat.  If you don't, you need to manually format the link URL to point to:  www.mydomain.com/my-menu-alias

I attached links for the router.php script, which are now relevant by following step 1.

http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component
http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs